# Why did the Mushishi anime air in a different order compared to the manga?

Tags: anime-production, mushishi

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mushishi_episodes), the order of the anime does not follow the same chronology as the manga. However, with the series being episodic (and relatively self contained), and each episode barely any passing reference to one another. Why did the production change up the order in the anime? Was there ever an officially stated reason?

Comment: A lot of time with episodic series like this, they will change up the order to affect the pacing. It's just one of those little things you need to think about when adapting a comic for the television screen. Edit: The one source that I could think of where you could find this info is the behind the scenes videos, cause that is a bit of information that might be in there. They talked about the order of the episodes and why for Firefly in their behind the scenes.